# Android Game Development. Type Usage for Entity Positions

Tags: java, android

I've recently started developing on Android and have made some basic apps. I now wish to start development on a game project. I have intermediate skill in Java and will be developing with that language in mind. I also have made a couple games for PC in java before. I will be using Native Android Studio for development and not an Engine/Framework.

My question is what is the preffered way to store object positions in Android for a **2D GAME**. 
The options I have right now are listed below:

- Int (Very basic, not precise)
- Float
- Double
- Custom Vector ADT
- Other native Android Type.

Comment: Depends on everything. Which have you tried and why were they deficient for your use-case?